# Angular upload video

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJs and i upload video dynamically but not every video playing just after 4-5 refresh of browser  everything is fine (video must displaying when mouse is on video)

```
 $timeout(function() {
            var video = element.find('video');
            video.hide();

            if (!video.length) {
                return;
            }

            video.find('source').attr('src', '/files/' + scope.game.videoPoster);

            element.on('mouseover', function() {
                video.show();
                video[0].play();
           });
           element.on('mouseout', function() {
               video.hide();
               video[0].pause();
           });
        }, 1);
```

Can anyone explain how to fix it?

Comment: Are you saying the video only plays after you refresh the browser 4-5 times?

Comment: yes i have 6 video posters and at least two of them didn't play when i just enter on site or if i refresh page with ctrl+shift+r

Comment: Does the video take time to load after you set its source?

Comment: no because it's just a poster 5-8 sec

Comment: i found  problem just put video.load()  after video.find...